# Emergency brake BLDC motor

Tags: safety, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, braking

I am redesigning a flawed safety system for an autonomous robot. The robot will drive alongside humans and roads, thus it needs redundancy. The braking is achieved in two ways:

- The motor controller of one wheel has a function called STO (safety torque off) which will stop the motor controller from applying any torque. Since the robot has two driven wheels and an idle steerable wheel, this will prevent the robot from driving straight on.
- The other wheel will be electrically (mechanically is not possible) braked. This is currently done by shorting the windings with a relay (G2R-2-SND from Omron). The stall current (short circuit current is not listed) from the [motor](https://www.maxongroup.nl/medias/sys_master/root/8882558861342/EN-21-279.pdf) is significantly higher than the maximum current of the relay (200 vs 5 A). Another problem is that the relay only shorts the windings and is wired in an NO configuration (this is required for pushing the robot when shutdown). If the relay is removed or broken, this system will do nothing which is not good.

My new proposition is to solve this with MOSFETs. These MOSFETs will be placed near the connector of the phase wires and will activate when the safety system is triggered. The motor controller is proprietary, so these external mosfets are needed.

The internal phase resistance of the motor is 119 mΩ, while the MOSFET resistance can be much lower e.g. 1.6 mΩ (FDB0165N807L). Provided the MOSFETs are switched on hard (vgs ~15 V and a strong MOSFET driver giving a total turn on of ~300 ns), will this work? And what other parameters do I need to look at? I am familiar with MOSFET SOA, and this MOSFET can handle the max BEMF at 100 A for 100 us which should be plenty. I am not familiar with avalanche ratings, do I need to take that into account for this application?

The robot weighs roughly 25 kg (50 pounds) and drives at a maximum speed of 3 m/s (6 mph). The total stored kinetic energy (112 J) will need to be dissipated in the motor windings if I understand it correctly.

The motors and geartrain provide enough friction to keep it from rolling down a hill. The brake is intended to slow it down enough to reduce risk.

The motor controller has integrated high side current sensing, so a phase to ground short is not a problem.

My question is whether the mosfets will be able to handle such a current spike that comes from shorting the phases.

[image: Controller + brake circuit]

Thanks!

Comment: How is the safety system any different than the three low-side mosfets?  Why not just turn off the three high side mosfets and turn on the three low-side mosfets? 

In your design, how will you make sure the high-side mosfets are off to make sure you don't get any shoot-thru currents?

Comment: You've forgotten to ask a question ... Or are you only wondering about avalanche ratings & nothing else?

Comment: `If the relay is removed or broken, this system will do nothing which is not good.` The same applies to the MOSFETs!  ie. Have you actually solved anything?

Comment: The motor controller is current limited, and sporadic phase shorts to ground are not a problem. Even if this would fail, the supply is fused.

Comment: Sometimes the relay needs to be removed due to an unforeseen maintenance issue. If it is not replaced, the problem arises. The mosfets can be integrated on the PCB, and don't have to be removed, fixing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask any question, so I will attempt to read your mind and assume that your unspoken question is: "Is this the best way to make a redundant emergency brake for the motor?"

Answer: not quite. When you turn on the 3 MOSFETs on the right, they may blow up due to current from the 3 MOSFETs at the top left.

Add a fuse in series with +Batt, and then the fuse will blow when you  turn on the 3 MOSFETs on the right. That will protect the MOSFETs, and the motor will brake.

Comment: Good point, I did not make my question clear. About the short: `The motor controller has integrated high side current sensing, so a phase to ground short is not a problem.`

Comment: I disagree, See, the only reason you're adding 3 MOSFETs if because you're assuming worst case, that the regular motor driver failed. If it fails, you can't trust anything about it:: current detection, current protection, shorted MOSFETs at the top. Therefore, you DO need a fuse. Look at it the other way: if you _do_ trust the motor driver, then you don't need the 3 extra MOSFETs because you can use the existing 6 MOSFETs to brake the motor.

Comment: `The motor controller is proprietary, so these external mosfets are needed.` That is why the external mosfets are needed, but you do absolutely have a fair point.

Comment: What? I don't understand you? If it is sarcasm, that's hard to decipher if it is not your native language.